# TensorFlowのチュートリアルコードについて

Tags: python3, tensorflow

TensorFlowのチュートリアルをながめているところなのですが、下記の部分はどういう意味なのか、記載ミスなのか教えてください。
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner?hl=ja

> predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
> predictions

２行目のpredictionsはどういう意味でしょうか？

Comment: `Run in Google Colab` と先頭近くにあり, 「このファイルは Google Colaboratory の notebook ファイルです」とも説明があります。上から順に試してみるとよいかも。
Jupyterや Google Colabでは, セルの最後の指定は 結果の表示で, この場合 変数 `predictions`の内容を表示するということ

Comment: 「どういう意味なのか」が, `model` とか `x_train`とか `numpy()` が何を指しているのかという意味なら, その旨記さないと質問として意味をなさないので, 質問は漠然と「何なのか」と尋ねるよりも, 「このように捉えたが合ってるか」などもう少し詳しく記したほうがよいかも

Comment: ありがとうございます。お聞きしたかったのは単に変数「predictions」のみを記載するのは、Pythonでは意味があるのか？ということです。Pythonをまだ勉強していないので、その点を端的にお聞きしたかったです。

Comment: 最後の行の「２行目のpredictionsはどういう意味でしょうか？」がお聞きしたいことです。

Answer (score 1):

`Run in Google Colab` と先頭近くにあり, 「このファイルは Google Colaboratory の notebook ファイルです」とも説明があります。上から順に試してみるとよいかも。

> ２行目のpredictionsはどういう意味でしょうか？

Pythonというより, Jupyter (lab | notebook) / Google [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) として, セルを実行する際 セルの最後の指定は結果の表示です。

この場合 変数 `predictions`の内容を表示するということです

Comment: ありがとうございました。Pythonファイルで実行していたので意味がわからなかったのですが、Google Colaboratory で実行してみて意味がわかりました。この行は気にする必要ないこともわかりました。